# How do I load a CBG GeoJSON into Python for Census Block Group level maps in Plotly?

Tags: python, geojson, census, plotly

I made county level maps a while ago and I'm trying to modify it to CBG level.

Am I limited to state and county?

```
with open('cbg.geojson') as response:
    cbgfile = json.load(response)     

data = pd.read_csv("roundone.csv")

fig = px.choropleth(data, geojson = cbgfile, locations='FIPS',           
                        scope = 'usa',
                        color = "bids_for_item",
                        #color_continuous_scale = ["white", "lime", "green"]            
                        )

fig.show()
```

I'm having issues loading the JSON (invalid argument). According to some other posts it might be because the GeoJSON is 3 GB. How could I get around that?

> File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/geojson/codec.py",
> line 43, in load
> **kwargs)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/**init**.py",
> line 296, in load
> return loads(fp.read(), OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Comment: Did you every figure this out, Ben Hendel? I would like to do something similar and was wondering this same question